# function Poison.encode_to_iodata!/1 is undefined

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm working on an elixir API for which I'm using JaSerializer but it's giving me an error something like this while I'm calling post API.

```
function Poison.encode_to_iodata!/1 is undefined (module Poison is not available)
```

But In my config file, I've added Poison and also recompile using mime

```
mix deps.clean mime --build
mix deps.get
```

Also the api which I'm calling is getting inserted into database but it's not responding any Json and giving me that error.

here's my config file:

```
use Mix.Config

config :banking,
  ecto_repos: [Banking.Repo]

# Configures the endpoint
config :banking, BankingWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  secret_key_base: "LMcWbj2QramA5ulI0MZnFobOtrKg/Z2x/gmDl6NwH7hxUbRksPzZjuXwyk8QKGyx",
  render_errors: [view: BankingWeb.ErrorView, accepts: ~w(json)],
  pubsub: [name: Banking.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2]

# Configures Elixir's Logger
config :logger, :console,
  format: "$time $metadata[$level] $message\n",
  metadata: [:request_id]

config :mime, :types, %{
  "application/vnd.api+json" => ["json-api"]
}

config :phoenix, :format_encoders,
  "json-api": Poison
# Use Jason for JSON parsing in Phoenix
config :phoenix, :json_library, Jason

# Import environment specific config. This must remain at the bottom
# of this file so it overrides the configuration defined above.
import_config "#{Mix.env()}.exs"
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
[error] #PID<0.583.0> running BankingWeb.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.582.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/banks
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Poison.encode_to_iodata!/1 is undefined (module Poison is not available)
        Poison.encode_to_iodata!(%{"data" => %{"attributes" => %{"name" => "arvind singh"}, "id" => "19", "type" => "bank"}, "jsonapi" => %{"version" => "1.0"}})
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:729: Phoenix.Controller.__put_render__/5
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:746: Phoenix.Controller.instrument_render_and_send/4
        (banking) lib/banking_web/controllers/bank_controller.ex:1: BankingWeb.BankController.action/2
        (banking) lib/banking_web/controllers/bank_controller.ex:1: BankingWeb.BankController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:288: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
        (banking) lib/banking_web/endpoint.ex:1: BankingWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (banking) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: BankingWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (banking) lib/banking_web/endpoint.ex:1: BankingWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:42: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
        (cowboy) /Users/apple/Documents/bankingassignment/banking/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:41: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
        (cowboy) /Users/apple/Documents/bankingassignment/banking/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:320: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
        (cowboy) /Users/apple/Documents/bankingassignment/banking/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:302: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Mix deps function

```
defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.9"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.1"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
      {:ja_serializer, github: "vt-elixir/ja_serializer"}
    ]
  end
```

Comment: Which version is defined in your deps? 
Can you please try running `mix deps.update --all`?

Comment: Can you also add your mix.exs file (its deps/0 function)?

Comment: Yes, I did this. Still getting the same error!

Comment: @julp can you take a look now?

Comment: Well, you need to add `{:poison, "~> 3.1"}` to your deps and then run `mix deps.get` again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to include `Poison` in your dependencies (your `deps` function in your `mix.exs` file).

When you put the following in your config:

```
config :phoenix, :format_encoders,
  "json-api": Poison
```

you're telling Phoenix that it should use Poison to handle JSON. Therefore, you should have `Poison` in your application. So, you should just add it in your `deps` function (it's at the end):

```
  defp deps do
    [
      {:phoenix, "~> 1.4.9"},
      {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.1"},
      {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 4.0"},
      {:ecto_sql, "~> 3.1"},
      {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
      {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
      {:jason, "~> 1.0"},
      {:plug_cowboy, "~> 2.0"},
      {:ja_serializer, github: "vt-elixir/ja_serializer"},
      {:poison, "~> 3.1"}
    ]
  end
```

You should take a look at [Jason](https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason), Phoenix now ships with it by default, and it is "blazing fast". In case you do want to add that, you should add `{:jason, "~> 1.1"}` to your dependencies instead of adding Poison, and replace `"json-api": Poison` for `"json-api": Jason` in your `config.exs`

Comment: I was using Jason before but how do I compare both which is better for my code?

Comment: Personally I think using "json-api": Poison saves a lot of time and gives more details

Comment: You could run a benchmark. For that purposes you can check out [benchee](https://github.com/bencheeorg/benchee). You could have both and run a couple of tests locally with benchee encoding/decoding simple objects, or test something that actually happens within your app, and that way you can get a good glance at how they compare. What exactly do you mean Poison gives more details?